# Angular-UI Bootstrap Modal grid row columns incorrect width

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to build a form in boostrap angular-ui modal, and am having an issue with using the default bootstrap grid in the `modal-body`

I build a `row` and then immediately build a `col-md-6` followed by another `col-md-6` and it is overflowing and colums are not next to each other like I would expect. I'm at a loss on this one.

Here is the HTML I have for the modal

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
<div class="modal-body">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove HoverMe pull-left CloseModalDark" ng-click="cancel()"></span>
    <form>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" ng-model="Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" ng-model="Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I know it's bad practice to link to your site, but I don't know any other way to demonstrate this behavior.

The "Sign Our Guestbook" link is how the modal that I am referencing is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra space you are seeing which is causing the overflow onto the new line is caused by your `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove HoverMe pull-left CloseModalDark" ng-click="cancel()"></span>` due to a conflict between the position styles.  The size and padding of the icon is still being set in place even though it's moved.

Answer (score 1):

Because your close icon:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove HoverMe pull-left CloseModalDark" ng-click="cancel()"></span>
```

Its styles include `position: relative;`, which occupies `26px` width of the `.row`. So the right input box is squeezed to next line. Make it `position:absolute` and adjust the `left` and `top` value. It will work.

Comment: @mituw16 My pleasure.